# Docker COPY failed: no source files were specified for only one project in multiproject solution

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

My project structure is something like this:

```
--Project.sln
----ProjectA.csproj
------Database
------Dockerfile
----ProjectB.csproj
--docker-compose.yml
--Dockerfile
```

Where ProjectA depends on and references ProjectB.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  dotnet-backend:
    container_name: dotnet-backend
    build: ./
    env_file: .env
    links:
      - mssql-db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  mssql-db:
    container_name: mssql-db
    build: ./ProjectA/Database
    volumes:
     - ./Database/:/scripts/
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln ./
COPY ./ProjectA/*.csproj ./ProjectA/
COPY ./ProjectB/*.csproj ./ProjectB/
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectA.dll"]
```

Now when I run docker-compose up --build I get this error:

```
Building dotnet-backend
Step 1/14 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
 ---> cfc38403c6bc
Step 2/14 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f88c69630ff
Step 3/14 : COPY *.sln ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2076128c94c
Step 4/14 : COPY ./ProjectA/*.csproj ./ProjectA/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41fdd541e0a8
Step 5/14 : COPY ./ProjectB/*.csproj ./ProjectB/
ERROR: Service 'dotnet-backend' failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

How come COPY works for ProjectA, but not for ProjectB? Never mind that it says `using cache` in step 4, I get the same error when building for the first time as well.

Comment: According to your files tree, your have **ProjectB.csproj**, is it a directory? But in your Dockerfile you are copying a content of **ProjectB** (`COPY ./ProjectB/*.csproj ./ProjectB/`) directory, but not **ProjectB.csproj**. Also are you sure you have **.csproj** files in your **ProjectB** directory?

Comment: For command `COPY ./ProjectB/*.csproj ./ProjectB/` ensure that folder name is correct (be careful about the case sensitivity)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into a similar problem, I was able to solve it after including `context` and `dockerfile` in docker-compose.yml file.

Previously Docker Compose was not able to find the files for the COPY command. Here is the fix:

```
services:
  webservice:
    build:
      context: ../             # your path to context
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile # path relative to context
```